# The difference of two ways generating a list in Python?

Tags: python

When I do an exercise, I want to generate a m*n list , and all the elements are 0.
I find an interesting question:

```py
# first way
a = [[0]*n]*m
a[0][0]=1
# then I find a[1][0]=1,a[2][0]=1....

# second way
b = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]
b[0][0]=1
# in this way, I get the normal effect
```

I am confused about the first way, what is the `*` means for list?

Comment: multiply and append

Comment: * here is sequence repetition of the items in the sequence n times

Answer (score 0):

The `*` operator essentially takes the old list, and recreates it `n` times.  The new items are the same (the same references) as the old ones, but the list if `n` times as long.

The original list is **not** modified, where simply appending new copies to the end would modify it.

Eg:

`[1,2,3] * 3 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]`

`[[1],[2]] * 3 = [[1],[2],[1],[2],[1],[2]]`

```
>>> myfunc = lambda: None
>>> a = [myfunc]
>>> a
[<function <lambda> at 0x03193468>]
>>> b = a * 2
>>> b
[<function <lambda> at 0x03193468>, <function <lambda> at 0x03193468>]
>>> a
[<function <lambda> at 0x03193468>]
>>> b is a
False
>>> a is b
False
```

Achieving the 'same' thing with `append`:

```
>>> X = [1,2]
>>> a = X.copy()
>>> n = 2
>>> b = a
>>> for i in range(n-1):
        for j in X:
            b.append(j)

>>> b
[1,2,1,2]
>>> a
[1,2,1,2]
>>> X
[1,2]
>>> a is b
True
>>> b is a
True
```

Comment: Not copies, just references

Comment: Appending each to the end is also not quite correct, it creates a new list

Comment: @DeepSpace this is misleading. the references copied are the references of the items within the original list, not of the reference to the original list itself.

Comment: If just references, so the space it ocupies is equal to [0]*n ?

Comment: @digger - References depend on whether it is a list of a value or reference type, it would be a good idea to see the duplicates.